# Set a full page popver on an iPad

Tags: ios, swiftui, ipados

Is there a way to set (or force) a `.popover` to present itself as a full page popover view like on iPhones instead of a small window with an arrow on iPad ?

Comment: SwiftUI 2.0 has `.fullScreenCover`. Does it fit your needs? Or use `.sheet`.

Comment: Yes .sheet fit for my purposes, thanks.